# Do I need to specify a border-color as a #value and a rgba?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have CSS code that looks like this:

```
#elementID {
   border-color: #51a351 #51a351 #387038;
   border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Can someone please explain. Do I need to specify these as two lines of CSS? I am confused. For example could the green color of the first CSS be part of the second rgba? Also do I really need the rgba.

Sorry if my question is a bit confusing. I took this code from the CSS used in Bootstrap 2.3 from a project I have been asked to tidy up for the very latest browser versions only.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean or not, but we write css[s] in this way, because old browsers don't support `rgba`, if they can't run the `rgba` they will use the color that you set before ( I mean hexadecimal colors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line gives a fallback color for [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors) which may not support `rgba`. If you don't need to support old browsers then you don't need to do this.

Comment: Yes,  I commented this too and I always write my css in this way, but I think I don't need to support people who are using old browsers!(+1 for you!)

Comment: I am not using any old browser so how could I convert the code to rgba? What confuses me here is the rgba colors are all 0,0,0. Why would that be?

Comment: @Marilou: The rgba border is black, but you see only 10% of it so it looks gray. I assume the background is supposed to be some kind of green so `#51a351 #51a351 #387038` looks like 10% black on top of that green.